# Adding sliding transition to ng-repeat div

Tags: css, angularjs, css-transitions, servicenow

Our team has created a widget in ServiceNow that shows a row of icons and show/hide additional details in a div when icons are clicked.  This is what our html and client controller looks like:

```html
<div class="icons">
  <ul class="flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <li ng-repeat="item in c.data.linksArray track by $index">
      <a class="link" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="c.getInfo(item)">
        <i title="{{item.titles}}" class='fa {{item.icon}} fa-3x circle-icon'></i>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="linkList text-center"
     ng-repeat="thing in c.data.linksArray track by $index"
     ng-if="thing.isVisible==true">
  <ul>
    <li class="m-b-sm" ng-repeat="link in thing.links">
      <a href="{{link.link_url}}">{{link.link_title}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```js
function($scope) {
    /* widget controller */
    var c = this;

    c.getInfo = function(item) {
        var isDisplaying = false;
        if(item.isVisible== true){
            isDisplaying = true;
        }

        for(var i=0; i<c.data.linksArray.length; i++){
            c.data.linksArray[i].isVisible = false;
        }

        if(isDisplaying == true){
            item.isVisible = false;
        }else{
            item.isVisible=!item.isVisible;
        }
    }

    console.log('icon-link-list');
    console.log($scope);
}
```

This all works fine, but we'd like to refine it by adding a sliding effect to the `.linkList` class.  Right now, when an icon is clicked, the `.linkList` div appears very abruptly.  Is there a way to add a sliding transition effect to that div using css?

Comment: try https://angular.io/guide/animations

Comment: @waqasMumtaz This is an AngularJS question. The documentation you link is for Angular 2+. They are different frameworks.

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Animations](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by pure css animations. Aplly this css to the item which will we hidden/shown. The animation will play anytime css attribute 'display' will change. I guess it's the linkList element?

```
.linkList {
animation: slideFromLeft .2s;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    opacity: 0;
}
@keyframes slideFromLeft{
  0% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  100% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: none;
  }
}
```

Edit: you maybe have to change `ng-if` on linkList to `ng-show`.

Comment: thanks Gordon!  this is super helpful.  I have 2 follow up questions to make it smoother.  1) When I click on an icon, it opens smoothly, but when I press the same icon again, the div closes very abruptly.  Is there a way to make that closing just as mooth as the opening?  2)  When I click on 1 icon, then immediately click on another, for a short time, both lists of links are on the screen, then a second later the original list disappears as expected.  Is there a way to fix that timing issue?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs:

> Animations in AngularJS are completely based on CSS classes. As long as you have a CSS class attached to an HTML element within your application, you can apply animations to it.
>
> As `ngRepeat` does its thing, each time a new item is added into the list, `ngRepeat` will add an `ng-enter` class to the element that is being added. When removed it will apply an `ng-leave` class and when moved around it will apply an `ng-move` class.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Animations](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations)